# My Normal Map makes my material black

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, texturing, materials, objects

When I apply an image texture to my material its fine.
But when I Connect a Normal Map The objectis black in rendered view.

Without Normal Map
[image]

With Normal Map
[image]

Also how do you add a .blend file in your posts?

Comment: You can add your blend file using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ Please pack the textures in it (or at least the normal map).

Comment: You might want to try assigning a UV map to the normal map node. It's currently blank. Also make sure your normals are facing the correct way.
In edit mode select all faces and press CTRL + N to recalculate all normals.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you set your normal map textures color mode to non-color data.

You have to do this in the texture settings AND in the properties panel of the cycles material node graph panel

Answer (score 3):

There is one other cause for Tangent Space normal maps turning black: if u are using microdisplacement (adaptive setting for subsurf modifier) normal map wont be able to calculate correctly, for this moment at least.

If you were to combine normal maps with "true" displacement, you can only choose between world and object space.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because your normals are not pointing in the right direction.

> Tangent space normal maps rely on the surface normal in the
>   approximation,so if the normals are not right the material won't work.

To recalculate your normal,select all faces in the mesh and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>,If this didn't work,you can check **invert**.

Comment: What do you mean by *invert* here? Is is just flipping Normals? If not, could you please explain how one can do it?

Comment: @Amir I think I meant use the *Flip Direction* operation in the shading panel.